# Display fields from multiple models in the standard list admin

Tags: python, django

How do I display fields from multiple models in the standard list admin?

I've designed my application as follows: (For simplicity, I omitted some fields)

models.py

```
class Register(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
    return self.tag


class Person(models.Model):
    register = models.OneToOneField(Register, primary_key=True)
    ownership_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.ownership_name
```

admin.py

```
class RegisterAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['tag', 'active', 'created_at', 'ownership_name (??)']n


admin.site.register(Register, RegisterAdmin)
```

The admin vision would be something like this:

+-------------------------------------------------------+
|  tag  | active | created_at | ownership_name |
|--------------------------------------------------------|
| XXX |    Yes    | 06/09/2104 |           John          |
|--------------------------------------------------------|
| YYY |    No     | 06/10/2104 |           Mark          |
+-------------------------------------------------------+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define additional fields in the admin class like so:

```
class RegisterAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['tag', 'active', 'created_at', 'ownership_name']

    def ownership_name(self, obj):
        return obj.person.ownership_name


admin.site.register(Register, RegisterAdmin)
```

Here are the docs on it: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display

Comment: Then can you mark my answer as the answer to your question?